# iphone 6 paul irish javascript crash

Tags: javascript, ios, css, infinite-scroll

I have added `infinite scroll`  to my tumbleblog and it seems to make the theme crash on iphone 6 plus. Having looked at other sites on the same phone using the same script, the problem seems to only happen on my tumbleblog.

The code I have used is below:

```
    (function () {
        var $tumblelog = $('.grid');
        $tumblelog.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: ".bar",
            nextSelector: ".next a",
            itemSelector: ".post",
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: '{lang:No more posts}',
                img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/cmghtlm/zWPnh0xhe/ajax-loader.gif',
                msgText: ''
            }
        },
        function (newElements) {
            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    })();
```

I wondered are there any CSS3 styles and transitions that affect `infinite scroll` or mobile browsers?

I am quite positive it is `infinite scroll` causing the issue. I tried removing it briefly and the problem seemed to disappear. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks !! :)

Example: http://ineedtreefiddy.tumblr.com/

Comment: You will need to post a live example for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Hey @mikedidthis . No problem dude, check this link. http://ineedtreefiddy.tumblr.com    To reproduce the problem you would most likely need an iphone. I have used iphone 6+ to reproduce to problem you would need inf scroll to be triggered once, and either tilt the screen into landscape and load up inf scroll again, or just spend 1 minute on the tumbleog crusing around and the browser should not last any longer than a minute without getting a "A problem occured with website" message and auto reloading. I have tested with chrome and opera also for iphone 6+ with same issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the CSS3 styles and transitions. I would do that to confirm `infinite scroll` is the culprit.